# Turn off the Github bot comment in pull request?

Tags: github

I'm trying to disable the GitHub action bot comment from my pull request but I'm not able to do it from the GitHub workflow file.

Can anyone help me, please?

[image: github bot comment]

Comment: This comes from some specific action that you're running, probably one called "Mega-Linter".  You'd probably want to look at the configuration for that tool.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that.